# Autoscroll UITableView in Modal Formsheet

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to implement a simple `UITableView` in an iPad `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` style dialog. Each cell in the `UITableView` has an embedded `UITextField`. Whenever I select one of the bottom text boxes, The FormSheet slides up, but the `UITableView` does not scroll, and the keyboard hides the input fields.

I have seen the discussion on how to resize a `UITableView` in these situations, and have implemended much of that code. I just need to know how I can calculate how much I need to shrink my `UITableView` to expose those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView it is available for free. Search on google for it.

Comment: I'm diggin this TableView Subclass. His code is also a good example of how to do this in the future as well. Thanks! Here is the source: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding